# Create a subrequest in a subrequest completion callback and a request body filter

Tags: c++, c, http, nginx, asynchronous

Referring to [NGINX Development guide - HTTP - Subrequests](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_subrequests), I managed to create the first subrequest with `NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_BACKGROUND | NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_IN_MEMORY` in a `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE` handler, and then the second subrequest with `NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_IN_MEMORY` in the completion callback of the previous request (no need to awake parent (main) request). After the second (last) subrequest callback is called, the main request is will be awaked by NGINX (`ngx_http_precontent_handler_by_em` will be called again).

Code snippet (some are omitted):

```cpp
// NGINX won't wake parent request (http wake parent request:)
#define NGX_HTTP_EM_SUBREQUEST_INTERMEDIATE NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_BACKGROUND | NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_IN_MEMORY

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_evaluation_done(ngx_http_request_t *req
    , void *data, ngx_int_t rc) {
    if (NGX_OK != rc) {
        ngx_rloge("subrequest@%p, data@%p, rc=%i", req, data, rc);
        return rc;
    }
    // req->main->content_handler = ngx_http_em_send_deny_response; // GOOD
    // ngx_http_em_send_deny_response(req->parent); // BAD
    // return NGX_HTTP_FORBIDDEN; // BAD
    return NGX_OK;
}

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_evaluation(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_http_em_ctx_t* ctx) {
    listener->handler = ngx_http_em_subrequest_file_done;
    listener->data = NULL;

    ngx_http_request_t *sr = NULL; // used to receive the new (sub-)request structure
    ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_subrequest(req, &sr_uri, &args, &sr, listener, NGX_HTTP_EM_SUBREQUEST_INTERMEDIATE);

    return NGX_OK;
}

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_token_done(ngx_http_request_t *req
    , void *data, ngx_int_t rc) {
    return ngx_http_em_subrequest_evaluation(req->parent, ctx);
}

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_token(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_http_em_ctx_t* ctx) {
    listener->handler = ngx_http_em_subrequest_token_done;
    listener->data = NULL;

    ngx_http_request_t *sr = NULL; // used to receive the new (sub-)request structure
    ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_subrequest(req, &sr_uri, &args, &sr, listener, NGX_HTTP_EM_SUBREQUEST_INTERMEDIATE);

    return NGX_OK;
}

ngx_int_t ngx_http_precontent_handler_by_em(ngx_http_request_t *req) {
    if (req->main != req) {
        logdf("req@%p vs req->main@%p, %.*s", req, req->main, ARGS_NGX_STR(req->uri));
        return NGX_DECLINED;
    }
    logdf("%.*s", ARGS_NGX_STR(req->uri));
    if (ctx) {
        if (ctx->hasAnyPending()) {
            return NGX_AGAIN;
        }
        if (0 == ctx->status) { 
            return NGX_OK; // NGX_HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
        }
        return NGX_DONE; // NGX_DECLINED;
    }
    // create ctx codes omitted for brevity ...
    ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_em_subrequest_token(req, ctx);
    if (NGX_ERROR != rc) {
        return NGX_DONE;
    }
    return NGX_OK;
}
```

However, if I created a subrequest in my request body filter, the request hanged until a bad gateway error.

```cpp
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list_done(ngx_http_request_t *req, void *data, ngx_int_t rc) {
    ngx_http_em_filter_request_body(req, ctx);
    ngx_http_next_request_body_filter(req, newchain);
    //req->parent->write_event_handler; // ngx_http_request_empty_handler
    return NGX_OK;
}

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_http_em_ctx_t* ctx) {
    listener->handler = ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list_fields_done;
    listener->data = NULL;
    ngx_int_t rc = ngx_http_subrequest(req, &sr_uri, &args, &sr, listener, NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_IN_MEMORY);
    return NGX_OK;
}

ngx_int_t ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_chain_t *in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logdf(LOG_SUBREQ "%.*s", LOG_SUBREQ_ARG(req), ARGS_NGX_STR(req->uri));
    if (in) {
        auto ctx = ngx_http_em_get_module_ctx(req);
        if (ctx) {
            ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list(req, ctx);
            return NGX_OK;
        }
    }
    return ngx_http_next_request_body_filter(req, in);
}
```

Does anyone know how to it?

```c
typedef struct {
    ngx_http_post_subrequest_pt       handler;
    void                             *data;
} ngx_http_post_subrequest_t;
```

Comment: C or C++, it can't be both.

Comment: My module was written by C++ (NGINX by C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, I traced and analyzed the NGINX code.

When a breakpoint is set at `ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em`, its callback looked like this:

```
    ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em(ngx_http_request_s * req, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 2637 C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_request_body_length_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 987    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_request_body_filter(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_chain_s * in) Line 923   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_read_client_request_body(ngx_http_request_s * r, void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *) post_handler) Line 102    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_proxy_handler(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 937   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_content_phase(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_phase_handler_s * ph) Line 1247  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 868 C
>   NGINX.exe!ngx_http_run_posted_requests(ngx_connection_s * c) Line 2408  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_handler(ngx_event_s * ev) Line 1287 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C
```

NGINX code snippet:

```c
ngx_int_t ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em(ngx_http_request_t *req, ngx_chain_t *in) {
    // u->read_event_handler = 0x00007ff7b74cf3f0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_upstream(ngx_http_request_s *, ngx_http_upstream_s *)}
    //req->main->posted_requests    0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   ngx_http_posted_request_s *
    //req->connection   0x0000029cc2080270 {data=0x0000029cc03e2e60 read=0x0000029cc20b8210 {data=0x0000029cc2080270 write=0 ...} ...}  ngx_connection_s *
    //req->main->write_event_handler    0x00007ff7b742c3ec {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_request_empty_handler}   void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
}

static ngx_int_t ngx_http_proxy_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    //...
    rc = ngx_http_read_client_request_body(r, ngx_http_upstream_init);
    if (rc >= NGX_HTTP_SPECIAL_RESPONSE) {
        return rc;
    }
    return NGX_DONE;
}

ngx_int_t ngx_http_core_content_phase(ngx_http_request_t *r, ngx_http_phase_handler_t *ph) {
    //...
    if (r->content_handler) {
        r->write_event_handler = ngx_http_request_empty_handler;
        ngx_http_finalize_request(r, r->content_handler(r));
        return NGX_OK;
    }
    //...
}

void ngx_http_core_run_phases(ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    //...
    while (ph[r->phase_handler].checker) {
        rc = ph[r->phase_handler].checker(r, &ph[r->phase_handler]);
        if (rc == NGX_OK) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void ngx_http_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    //...
    r->write_event_handler = ngx_http_core_run_phases;
    ngx_http_core_run_phases(r);
}

void ngx_http_run_posted_requests(ngx_connection_t *c) {
    // https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23023/iterate-vs-iterate-over
    //... Iterates ((ngx_http_request_t*)(c->data))->main->posted_requests
    for ( ;; ) {
        r->write_event_handler(r);
    }
}
```

In `ngx_http_run_posted_requests`, I found `r->write_event_handler` may be one of the following functions:

```
0x00007ff7b742baf0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_handler}
0x00007ff7b742c3ec {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_request_empty_handler}
0x00007ff7b74d42f0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_wr_check_broken_connection(ngx_http_request_s *)}
0x00007ff7b74cc5c0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_downstream(ngx_http_request_s *)}
0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
```

As a result, I found that `ngx_http_upstream_init` was not called after `ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list_done`.

In addition, I also inspected and recorded values of `req->write_event_handler`, `req->main->posted_requests` and `req->main->write_event_handler` when those `ngx_http_post_subrequest_pt` handlers are called:

```
    req->write_event_handler    0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
    req->main->posted_requests  0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   ngx_http_posted_request_s *
    req->main->write_event_handler  0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)

>   ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_em_subrequest_attributes_done(ngx_http_request_s * req, void * data, __int64 rc) Line 1684  C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, __int64 rc) Line 2465   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_rewrite_phase(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_phase_handler_s * ph) Line 937   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 868 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_handler(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 852 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_run_posted_requests(ngx_connection_s * c) Line 2408  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_process_request_headers(ngx_event_s * rev) Line 1502 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_process_request_line(ngx_event_s * rev) Line 1153    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_wait_request_handler(ngx_event_s * rev) Line 501 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C


    req->write_event_handler    0x00007ff7b74cc5c0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_downstream(ngx_http_request_s *)}   void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
    req->main->posted_requests  0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   ngx_http_posted_request_s *
    req->main->write_event_handler  0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)

>   ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_em_subrequest_token_done(ngx_http_request_s * req, void * data, __int64 rc) Line 1295   C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, __int64 rc) Line 2465   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u, __int64 rc) Line 4495 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 4051  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_upstream(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 3963 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_send_response(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 3241    C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_process_header(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_upstream_s * u) Line 2435   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_handler(ngx_event_s * ev) Line 1286 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C


    req->write_event_handler    0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
    req->main->posted_requests  0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   ngx_http_posted_request_s *
    req->main->write_event_handler  0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)

>   ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_em_subrequest_evaluation_done(ngx_http_request_s * req, void * data, __int64 rc) Line 1368  C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, __int64 rc) Line 2465   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_rewrite_phase(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_phase_handler_s * ph) Line 937   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 868 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_handler(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 852 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_run_posted_requests(ngx_connection_s * c) Line 2408  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_handler(ngx_event_s * ev) Line 1287 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C


    req->write_event_handler    0x00007ff7b742bf19 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases} void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)
    req->main->posted_requests  0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   ngx_http_posted_request_s *
    req->main->write_event_handler  0x00007ff7b74d42f0 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_wr_check_broken_connection(ngx_http_request_s *)}   void(*)(ngx_http_request_s *)

>   ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list_done(ngx_http_request_s * req, void * data, __int64 rc) Line 1896 C++
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_s * r, __int64 rc) Line 2465   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_rewrite_phase(ngx_http_request_s * r, ngx_http_phase_handler_s * ph) Line 937   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_core_run_phases(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 868 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_handler(ngx_http_request_s * r) Line 852 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_run_posted_requests(ngx_connection_s * c) Line 2408  C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_handler(ngx_event_s * ev) Line 1287 C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_event_process_posted(ngx_cycle_s * cycle, ngx_queue_s * posted) Line 35   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_process_events_and_timers(ngx_cycle_s * cycle) Line 265   C
    NGINX.exe!ngx_worker_thread(void * data) Line 795   C
```

Now, after I added `ngx_http_em_subrequest_sp_list_done`, the `curl` client could receive the response.

```cpp
        // assert(ngx_http_upstream_wr_check_broken_connection == req->parent->write_event_handler);
        // assert(ngx_http_request_empty_handler == req->parent->write_event_handler);
        req->parent->write_event_handler = ngx_http_core_run_phases;
```